# Delphi - E2003 Undeclared Identifier Issue

Tags: delphi

I've got a really bizarre issue occurring in the Delphi XE2 IDE.

In one package, I have the following classes declared:

```
TCommandInfo = class
    private
        fParameters : TCommandParameters;
        // other fields...
    public
        property Parameters : TCommandParameters read fParameters;
        // other properties...
end;

TReceiveCommand = class(TCommand)
    // other fields and properties
    private
        fInfo : TCommandInfo;

    public
        property Info : TCommandInfo read fInfo;

end;


TReceiveErrorCommand = class(TReceiveCommand);

TReceiveDataCommand = class(TReceiveCommand)
    // procedures and properties defined, etc.
end;
```

Now in a completely different package which depends on the package above, I have this member function:

```
procedure DoDataCommand;
var
    cmd : TReceiveDataCommand;
    success : Boolean;
    params : TCommandParameters;
begin
    cmd := TReceiveDataCommand.Create;
    success := cmd.Initialize;

    if success then begin
        // #### ERROR HERE ####
        params := cmd.Info.Parameters;
    end;
end;
```

What I'm seeing is that when trying to compile the dependent package, I get an E2003 error saying "Undeclared identifier: 'Info'" and when I CTRL+CLICK on the TReceiveDataCommand to take me to the declaration, the IDE jumps to a different location in the containing packages source file.

I have this very same code running on my machine at work and this works without fail. I'm wondering if there are some lingering BPL's lurcking around somewhere however I've had a good clear out.

It seems odd that the IDE takes me to the wrong location when trying to jump to the TReceiveDataCommand class source.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I guess you are using an out of date dcp file

Comment: I've done a clean/clean all about 5 times now and it has made no difference

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? I'm fiddling with your example now for few hour and only once I managed to kind of reproduce your problem. That was on Delphi XE8 where IDE was reporting that there is no field in a class even thou code insight offered it inside the class constructor. So I couldn't even compile the code in first place. When I copied that code to Delphi XE3 it compiled without the problem. When I then copied that code from Delphi XE3 into a new project in Delphi XE8 it also compiled and worked without any problems. ...

Comment: ... So I guess there might be something wrong with the code editor so that it sends broken code to the compiler itself. But I haven't seen anything like this before and yet I heavily use custom made classes.

Answer (score 1):

The `TReceiveCommand` type is defined in a different package. The compiler uses the .dcp file to resolves names in that different package. If `Info` is not recognised then clearly the .dcp file that the compiler is finding does not match the source code in the question.

The logical conclusion is that the compiler is finding an out of date .dcp file.

Comment: I'll do a file search of my system, see if there is a hidden file I don't know about...

Comment: Ok, so the issue has now been resolved. For one reason or another, a very old version of the package appeared in the package bpl 'requires' list - which doesn't make any sense to me because I've built this package from new and there has been no reference made to this old, obsolete package. This old version did not contain an "Info" property.

Comment: No, that's not it. You report a compilation error. The bpl file is only used at runtime. Your problem is as I described.

Comment: When the package appears in the BPL requires list, the compilation error occurs. When I remove the package from the BPL requires list, I get no compilation error - nothing else has changed. If there is something I am missing by doing this single action, I'm at a loss to know what.

Comment: It seems that you aren't interested in learning about this, judging by your comments. I'm not going to force you to listen. If you want to learn, let me know.

Comment: I'm confused, where have I indicated that I'm not interested? As far as I'm aware, the issue has been resolved due to a conflicting item in the requires list but you're saying that isn't the issue - but my project compiles. Apologies, but I'm confused...

Comment: You keep talking about bpl files, but they are absolutely not the issue. You won't entertain the possibility that the problem is with a dcp file. I think I answered your question. You clearly don't agree because you did not accept the answer.

Comment: I have tried your solution but for me, it doesn't work as ALL the files the compiler finds are up to date (via a manual delete and rebuild-all) however the only solution that works is the one I've mentioned. Again, I'm just at a loss to understand why the solution isn't the solution, I'm clearly missing something but so far I'm struggling to understand what that is.

Comment: Until you are prepared to believe me that the .bpl file is not used at compile time, I'm not interested in spending more time here. It's no fun for me.

Comment: I have never said that I don't believe you that its not used at compile time, I can't see anywhere where I have indicated this but if you've got the impression from my comments, then I apologise. I'm here to learn and try out what people suggest and post back if things work/don't work - but surely if they don't work, they just don't work.

Comment: Maybe the issue is not that my answer is wrong, but that you don't yet understand what I am saying? The interface of a package is described by the compiler generated dcp file, and whichever dcp file describes `TReceiveDataCommand` clearly does not match the code in the question.

Comment: Ok, I agree with that. So if the compiler is generating the interfaces file from the same source which contains all the correct definitions, how can this issue occur? Which (bear with me) brings me back to my "requires" solution - it seems that the compiler is using this list of requirements to generate the interface DCP file. Would you not agree with that?

Comment: `requires` tells the compiler which packages to reference. At compile time it references the dcp file for the package.

Comment: Ok, so, there is a package in the requires list which contains a TReceiveCommand class which doesn't contain the Info property as its from a previous version - I don't know how this got into the requires list as I certainly didn't add it in. Surely then, this would indicate that the compiler is using the DCP file from this previous release, rather than the one for the current package?

Comment: Yes. That's what my answer says.

Comment: So therefore removing the old package from the "requires" list does fix the problem.

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: But the only way I've found to resolve it is to remove it from the "requires" list - in the BPL - as I mentioned right at the start...

Comment: No. The bpl file is the executable package module. It's the output file. Do you mean the dpk file? Do you need to refresh your knowledge of the files related to a package?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen only when I migrated from `Xe6` to `xe7`.  It was linking in both the `xe6` stuff and `xe7`.  As the project conversion/migration had not done its job.  I would check the paths in the `dproj` files.

And now for a completely obvious question - have you rebuilt ?